# Need software to open mdb file of OpenLdap

Tags: ms-access, openldap

my zimbra mail system broken, my mdb file of OpenLdap corrupted so now i can not rebulid my zimbra system mail. I need tool or software to open the corrupted MDB file of OpenLdap to find the reason.

Sorry my english not good.

Answer (score 0):

Without Access, your first attempt would be this tool:
[Jet Compact Utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295334)

Comment: thanks for your advice but Jet Compact Uti can not open this MDB file

Comment: That's bad. Then you are left with the backup from yesterday or to bing/google for a service that - for money - restore severely damaged Access files.